# logging failed queries

Tags: mysql

I can log all the mysql queries by enabling the general log. But it does not show the failed queries.

Is there a way to save failed queries as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does show failed queries.
There is no easy way of segregating them.

Comment: I am totally surprised to see that general log is really recording everything! even the failed queries. The slow and binary logs won't have those queries. Correct?

Comment: slow query log only shows slow queries, regardless if they execute correctly I believe.
Binary log shows all non-failed queries. Nonetheless, the binary log is for internal use only ( maily to rebuild a db should there be a power failure o similar)

Answer (score 0):

You can log ALL queries by setting the `sql_log_off` variable to `0` (you should have super privilegies)

or you can log failed queries by `PHP`:

```
  function sql_query($data)
  {
      $sql = mysql_query($data);
      if($sql == FALSE){
           //do some logging here.
           $fh = fopen("log.txt", 'a') or die("can't open file");
           fwrite($fh, "\n MYSQL ERROR @".microtime(true).": QUERY:".$data."\n");
      }
      return $sql;
  }
```

Comment: Always remember to close file pointers, and a cleaner method would be to use `file_put_contents('log.txt', "\nError message", FILE_APPEND);`